# How to exclude selected items in PrimeNG PickList?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am writing an "update" page and use PrimeNG PickList. The target list is not empty at initial. The PrimeNG doesn't remove the selected items from source list.

As far as I understand, PrimeNg calls "==" operator in the background. However, I can't override the operator. How can I override it and exclude the selected items?

Comment: Its true, i can confirm this issue. Any workaround ?

Comment: You can try to filter sourceArray on app init or even onAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few months old, but hopefully it helps someone! I ended up doing a filter on the source array like so:

```
this.availableRoles = allRoles.filter(userRole => {
    return !this.user.userRoles.some(x => x.id === userRole.id && x.name === userRole.name);
});
```

I made sure to call this code after I had already subscribed to a few requisite objects (namely, I had to get the list of all roles available in my system, and I had to get the desired user including his/her inherited roles).

Then, in the HTML template, I bound [source] to availableRoles and [target] to the userRoles property on my user object.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. May not be the best way cause it's O(n)^2 but hey it works great for a short source list.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < this.list2.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < this.list1.length; j++){
    if(this.list1[j].name === this.list2[i].name){
      this.list2.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
}
this.newList2 = this.list2;
```